# convert multiple subquery from same table to one query

Tags: sql, oracle

Here i am trying to convert three different subquery from same table to one subquery which will distribute into three different column.

Can it be possible.?
My Actual query is---

```
select p.pi_no,( SELECT pu_DATE
                 FROM tabl1
                 WHERE pi_no   = p.pi_no
                   AND si_no  = 45
               ) AS con_date,
               ( SELECT pu_DATE
                 FROM tabl1
                 WHERE pi_no   = p.pi_no
                   AND si_no     = 46
               ) AS subjvis,
               ( SELECT pu_DATE
                 FROM tabl1
                 WHERE pi_no   = p.pi_no
                   AND event_no     = 47
               ) AS initDate
from public p;
```

Want to convert to like this

```
select tu.pi_no, ( SELECT pu_DATE
                   FROM tabl1
                   WHERE pi_no   = tu.pi_no
                   AND si_no  IN( 45,46,47)
                 )
from public tu;
```

Want output to look like this:

```
PI_NO || con_date(45) || subjvis(46) || initDate(47)
----------------------------------------
1234  || 14-DEC-2017 || 12-DEC-2017||15-DEC-2017
```

Can this be achievable in oracle

Comment: Are you trying to join `public` and `tabl1` tables? If so, what field is the join on?

Comment: @Vashi Trying to join based on `pi_no   = p.pi_no` . PI_NO is available in public and tabl1

Comment: This last scalar query has this condition, `AND event_no     = 47`.  Is this supposed to be, `AND si_no     = 47`?

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the subqueries by joins

```
SELECT
    tu.pi_no,
    t1.pu_date AS con_date,
    t2.pu_date AS subjvis,
    t3.pu_date AS initDate
FROM
   public tu
   LEFT JOIN tabl1 t1 ON tu.pi_no = t1.pi_no AND t1.si_no = 45
   LEFT JOIN tabl1 t2 ON tu.pi_no = t2.pi_no AND t2.si_no = 46
   LEFT JOIN tabl1 t3 ON tu.pi_no = t3.pi_no AND t3.si_no = 47
```

You cannot return more than one column from a subquery in the select list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are joining on `pi_no` field then below join should work. If for a given `pi_no`, a particular value of `si_no` say 45 is not found, then a NULL would be populated. Try:

```
SELECT tu.pi_no,
CASE WHEN a.si_no = 45 THEN a.pu_DATE ELSE NULL END AS con_date,
CASE WHEN a.si_no = 46 THEN a.pu_DATE ELSE NULL END AS subjvis,
CASE WHEN a.si_no = 47 THEN a.pu_DATE ELSE NULL END AS initDate
FROM
PUBLIC tu
LEFT JOIN
tabl1 a
ON tu.pi_no = a.pi_no;
```

Comment: `tabl1` has more records than `public`. This will yield too many records

Comment: It is not clear about the type of relation(one-to-many, one-to-one, etc.) based on the description. Which of the two tables do you want all the `pi_no` to be displayed from? Your main table.

Comment: Since the OP queries `si_no  = 45`, `si_no  = 46` and `si_no  = 47`, there must be at least three records per `pi_no` in `public` unless only one of them yields something. I.e. your query works only if at least 2 of the 3 columns are NULL. And there might be more of them like `si_no  = 50`.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Conditional Logic with the Aggregate Function, MAX, to Obtain the Scalar Subquery Values with the Granularity of Table, PUBLIC**

The goal is to return all records of the object, `public` (that name is less than ideal because it is a [keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621)). Since the presumed key of the object, `PUBLIC`, is `pi_no`, we place this column in the group by clause to ensure that the query's granularity is identical.

We take the max of the conditional logic to obtain the record where there is a value (assumes the key for `tabl1` is `pi_no, si_no`).

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT
    p.pi_no,
    MAX(DECODE(si_no,45,t.pu_date,TO_DATE(NULL) ) ) con_date,
    MAX(DECODE(si_no,46,t.pu_date,TO_DATE(NULL) ) ) subjvis,
    MAX(DECODE(si_no,47,t.pu_date,TO_DATE(NULL) ) ) initdate
FROM
    public p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tabl1 t ON pi_no = p.pi_no
                               AND si_no IN ( 45, 46, 37)
GROUP BY
    p.pi_no;
```